# Универсальное регулярное выражение для времени

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Необходимо написать регулярное выражение, которому удовлетворяли бы следующие форматы, если это возможно:

```
HH:MM:SS

H:MM:SS

MM:SS

M:SS
```

Comment: Конечно возможно. Необходимо - напишите. Что именно вы пробовали сделать и что у вас не получилось.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://regex101.com/r/yI8aS6/1
Выражение

```
\b(?=\d+:\d)((?:(?:2[0-3]|[0-1]?[0-9]):(?=\d\d))?(?:[0-5]?[0-9]:)?[0-5][0-9])\b
```

Свободная запись:

```
\b # граница слова
(?=\d+:\d) # требование, чтобы справа были цифры, двоеточие, снова цифра
((?:(?:2[0-3]|[0-1]?[0-9]):(?=\d\d))? # HH то есть 0-23, двоеточие и две цифры справа обязательно, чтобы не было HH:M:SS
(?:[0-5]?[0-9]:)? # MM то есть 0-59, двоеточие
[0-5][0-9])\b # SS то есть 0-59 и граница слова
```

https://regex101.com/r/yI8aS6/2
Второй вариант выражения

```
(?:[^\d:]|^)\b(?=\d+:\d)((?:(?:2[0-3]|[0-1]?[0-9]):(?=\d\d))?(?:[0-5]?[0-9]:)?[0-5][0-9])\b
```

Добавляем

```
(?:[^\d:]|^) # не цифра, двоеточие или начало строки
```

Не дает частично совпасть `61:34:23` и.т.п..
В этом выражении результат в первой группе, полное совпадение может содержать лишний литерал.

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо огромное!